# Illustrator - not outlining entire path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

This is ridiculous: I have a simple looping path. It has a stroke and a fill. I apply "Object > Path > Outline Stroke" and it only applies to *half* the path.

If I break the loop in two places, it works, but the ends don't join well. If I break it in one place, it still doesn't work. If I delete any number of points, it *still* screws up.

**EDIT:** I also just tried outlining it, deleting the bad stroke, and re-outlining the fill - but that doesn't work either - I think there's something wrong with the shape.

## EDIT:

Wow. So, I retraced it manually and approximately, and it *still* didn't work, **but not only that, I messed up one of the tangents, and suddenly it works**. It's the unique shape that is an exception. This is definitely an AI bug.

Screenshots:

[image: Before Stroke]

[image: After Stroke]

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: No clue. Trash preferences perhaps. If the same thing happens with a newly drawn path, check the Appearance panel for any unusual settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know if the question can be answered since I can say nothing more than that it is simply an AI bug for *sure*, if you'll observe; nonetheless, the slight compromise will suffice for my needs:

[image: Positive slope doesn't work, yet zero or negative slope does]

Weird :-?

As a wild guess, it really looks like it's some kind of issue with the determination logic for the bisection of the angles at the anchors - I did another test, and it did do the whole path, but there was a slight pie-sliver break at one of the anchors

Comment: Most likely `Object > Expand` (which does the same thing) won't show the issue. I rarely use "outline stroke".

Comment: Well, no, I'm pretty sure it still did.